# FabricViewStateManager: setState called without a StateWrapper

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ble-plx

I am an iOS developer venturing into Android dfor the first time using React-native.

I am creating a react-native app that uses bluetooth-le, using polidieas react-native-ble-plx library.  iOS app works fine, bluetooth scans and detecgts devices.  When i run on Android, it starts to scan and I receive an error "FabricViewStateManager: setState called without a StateWrapper" and cannot find any documentation or help for this error statement.

Two questions:

1. has anyone seen this error reported when running React-Native Apps on Anmdroid: FabricViewStateManager: setState called without a StateWrapper.
2. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to isolate where the error is occurring?

Here is the console right before the error:

```
I/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
I/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
I/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
I/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=13 mScannerId=0
I/ReactNative: [GESTURE HANDLER] Initialize gesture handler for root view com.facebook.react.ReactRootView{67ef486 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,2019 #1}
**E/unknown:FabricViewStateManager: setState called without a StateWrapper**
I/ReactNativeJS: ┐ %c action %cCHANGE_STATUS %c@ 20:36:54.384
I/ReactNativeJS: │ '%c prev state', 'color: #9E9E9E; font-weight: bold', { BLEs: 
       { BLEList: [],
         color: '#800080',
         oldColor: '#000000',
         intensity: 127,
         connectedDevice: {},
         status: 'disconnected' } }
    │ '%c action    ', 'color: #03A9F4; font-weight: bold', { type: 'CHANGE_STATUS', status: 'Scanning' }
I/ReactNativeJS: │ '%c next state', 'color: #4CAF50; font-weight: bold', { BLEs: 
       { BLEList: [],
         color: '#800080',
         oldColor: '#000000',
         intensity: 127,
         connectedDevice: {},
         status: 'Scanning' } }
    ┘ 
    ┐ %c action %cADD_BLE %c@ 20:36:54.391
I/ReactNativeJS: │ '%c prev state', 'color: #9E9E9E; font-weight: bold', { BLEs: 
       { BLEList: [],
         color: '#800080',
         oldColor: '#000000',
         intensity: 127,
         connectedDevice: {},
         status: 'Scanning' } }
I/ReactNativeJS: │ '%c action    ', 'color: #03A9F4; font-weight: bold', { type: 'ADD_BLE',
      device:
```

Comment: Found a solution yet?

Comment: Any solution ... ?

Comment: Might have the same problem. Any solutions found?

Comment: Ayn solutions founds @CristianoCoelho?

Comment: @DiegoSantaCruzMendezú Nothing so far

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no answer for this yet.  See this issue posted against the `facebook/react-native` project in GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32070.

It may have something to do with `react-native-reanimated`, if you're using it, which has been the cause of some cryptic crashes with the latest version of RN (see [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/2290) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32037), for example).  They've apparently resolved the issues in the recent `2.2.2` release (on 14 SEP 21) and their `2.3.0-alpha`.